# How to create a Windows application that: detects current program and sends shortcuts

Tags: windows, programming-languages

I would like to create an application for Windows that is visible in the system tray and can detect the current open window. The application that I want to make should also be able to "press on the users keyboard": sending out keyboard shortcuts to the current open window/application.

How would I go about doing this? What programming languages/tools would be useful?

Best would even be if it is portable to Mac, but this is not a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portability: Not very likely you can find anything that is cross-platform for this.

For Windows: AutoIt. Does everything you want and a lot more.

For Mac: Applescript (standard component of OSX) can probably do this, but I could be wrong about that. I do have a Mac, but I never had a reason to play around with this sort of stuff.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :) I forgot to mention that the application needs to exchange data with a server (using XML preferably, otherwise just data seperated with newlines or something like that). Would you like to advise me on how I would do this in AutoIt?

Comment: That is a much to complicated subject to discuss here. Just play around with AutoIt and look at the code samples on the web-site. Plenty of information how to write files from AutoIt.